# Need more active mods on Beer.SE

Tags: discussion

We have three Pro Tempore moderators on this site.  As of this moment, one last visited the site 13 hours ago.  (No problem with that.)  The second last visited the site 25 days ago. (Problem with that.)  The third last visited the site two and a half months ago.  (Big problem with that.)

Flags aren't being dealt with for days, which tells me that we need more moderator activity on the site.  I know the site as a whole is pretty inactive, but that's brought into even sharper focus by the apparent lack of moderation.

An organized, useful site is going to draw in more new users than one strewn with junk.

Comment: Just to let you know, I've asked about the possibility of reassigning pro tempore mods (open to including myself) on the moderators' chat and have reached out to the other mods. I'm now about to reach out to a staff member for additional help. Thanks for bringing this up.

Comment: @AndrewCheong Thanks Andrew, and to be clear, I've never had an issue with the quantity or quality of your moderation work here...Only with the fact that there are no other mods who seemed to be equally engaged.

Comment: Congratulations on your promotion!

Comment: @NormalHuman Thanks!  :-)

Comment: @Xander Hi! What is the state of the art about this matter in particular? I mean as of 2019.

Comment: @MattAllegro I'm happy to report that the situation is much better now. I was not a moderator when I posted this question...A year later I was asked to step up and help and I did, and in 2016 we had new  Pro Tempore appointments and have now had the same stable of three consistently active moderators for over three years.